# How to add a dropdown menu on top of a UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableView as the entering page of my application. I want to have something like a dropdown menu on top of the table to let the user navigate to other pages. I tried to implement a UIPickerView but the UITableViewController cannot implement its delegate and datasource protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put this dropdown not on table view cells you need to use `UIViewController` instead `UITableViewController`. And add to view controllers's view the dropdown and table view.

---